# PHP posting multiple data using checkbox as a criteria

Tags: php, forms, post, checkbox

I am doing a project regarding twitter API, but I cannot post data that is checked into another php for editing! I am creating a website that allows my user to select tweets they searched from twitter, edit it in a textarea before posting it into the database.

Here is the scenario! Currently, I had retrieved the username and the user's tweet from Twitter. But I am unable to post selected tweets to another page.

Here is the codes that puts the usernames and tweets that meets the search criteria into a form with checkbox using array call doSearchTweet.php.

```
foreach ($json->results as $result)
    {
        for($i=0;$i<$result;$i++){
            $tweet[$i]= $result->text;
            $user[$i]= $result->from_user;
        ?>
        <tr><td width="300" align="center"><input type="text" name="username[]" readonly="readonly" style="border:0" value="<?php echo $user[$i] ?>"></td>
        <td width="400"><textarea cols="80" rows="3" name="content[]" readonly="readonly" style="border:0" ><?php echo $tweet[$i] ?></textarea></td>
        <td width="150" align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="add[]" value="1"/></td></tr>
        <?php
        }
    }
```

After the user selected the tweets they wanted to edit/post, it will post them to createPost.php using these codes.

```
for ($i=0;$i<20;$i++){
   if ($select[$i] == 1){
     echo $user[$i].'<br/>';
     echo $content[$i].'<br/>';
   }
}
```

The results shows that no matter which one I checked. I will just post the number of arrays I checked and not the specific one I checked.

> For Example: If I checked tweets 0, 2, 4 
>   It will always post 0, 1, 2

How can I change my code so that if I select 0, 2, 4. It will post username and tweets that belongs to array number 0, 2, 4?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the add array defined by the checkboxes always starts from 0. If a checkbox is not checked, it will not appear in add[].

You should give the checkboxes the value of the current index $1:

`<input type="checkbox" name="add[]" value="<?php echo $i ?>"/>`

and then loop over the checkbox array:

```
foreach ($add as $i) {
     echo $user[$i].'<br/>';
     echo $content[$i].'<br/>';
}
```

UPDATE to comment #15

You need to get a valid id within your result loop:

```
<?php
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($json->results as $result) {
        $tweet[$i]= $result->text;
        $user[$i]= $result->from_user;
?>
        YOUR HTML
<?php
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: This might be true. Please check the variable names. Perhaps "add" is not the destination of your checkbox values. Your PHP example above did say: $select for example.

Comment: I guess you have checked the first tweet. But what about this trailing "/" after the 0 ?

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't want us to add that much comments. So the next you can test is your HTML. What are the values of the checkboxes in HTML?

Comment: Then this is the place to fix. Should be the value of $i within the loop.

Comment: I think my value for $i is within the loop but I cannot find the error. Can you help me check?

Comment: I could run this code properly. Try to clear the browser cache.

Comment: ok understand. the problem is probably this line: `for($i=0;$i<$result;$i++)` where $result is not a number but an object. Try to replace with `count($results)`.

Comment: Please do accept this answer as the right answer by clicking the grey checkbox.